# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python, image, button, nonetype

What I am trying to do here is add the image to the button I have, then based on click or hover change the image. All the examples I have followed use the `.config()` method.

For the life of me I can't figure out why it doesn't know what the button object is. What is interesting is that if I modify the Button definition line to include the image option, everything is fine. But, with that there it seems I can't modify it using `.config()`

```
PlayUp = PhotoImage(file=currentdir+'\Up_image.gif')
PlayDown = PhotoImage(file=currentdir+'\Down_image.gif')
#Functions
def playButton():
    pButton.config(image=PlayDown)
pButton = Button(root, text="Play", command="playButton").grid(row=1)
pButton.config(image=PlayUp)
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
pButton = Button(root, text="Play", command="playButton").grid(row=1)
```

Here you are creating an object of type `Button`, but you are immediately calling the `grid` method over it, which returns `None`. Thus, `pButton` gets assigned `None`, and that's why the next row fails.

You should do instead:

```
pButton = Button(root, text="Play", command="playButton")
pButton.grid(row=1)
pButton.config(image=PlayUp)
```

i.e. first you create the button and assign it to `pButton`, *then* you do stuff over it.

Comment: Aha that's great. So simple. I have made the change, any idea why my image doesn't change on click though?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it helps in similar cases:

```
mywidget = Tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=myvar,width=10).pack()
mywidget.config(bg='red')
```

This generates this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

But everythings run smoothly if I write on separate lines:

```
mywidget = Tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=myvar,width=10)
mywidget.pack()
mywidget.config(bg='red')
```

I do not understand it but it took me a lot of time to solve... :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
canvas = tk.Tk()
canvas.title("Text Entry")

text_label = ttk.Label(canvas, text = "Default Text")
text_label_1 = ttk.Label(canvas, text = "Enter Your Name: ").grid(column = 0, row = 1)
text_variable = tk.StringVar()
text_entry = ttk.Entry(canvas, width = 15, textvariable = text_variable)
text_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
def change_greeting():
    text_label.configure(text = "Hello " + text_variable.get())
event_button = ttk.Button(canvas, text="Click me and see what happens", command = change_greeting).grid(column = 2, row = 1)
text_label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
canvas.resizable(False, False)
canvas.mainloop()
```

In the above code `text_label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)` is placed at the end that is after all the operations on the label is completed. 
If  `text_label = ttk.Label(canvas, text = "Default Text").grid(column = 0, row = 0)`  is done in the above code then the error will be produced. Hence being cautious about the display of objects is necessary

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have found that packing using one-liners such as
`btt = Button(root,text='Hi Button').pack()`

have been messing with the object data type for example setting it to `NoneType`
but if you use `.pack` after like this
`btt.pack()`
this will mitigate most issues related to tkinter.