# can't background color in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

I'm growing desperate with this simple tkinter program: I can't seem to be able to change the background color (or the color of the individual widgets)! What is going wrong here?

Below is a gist of the various attempts that I and the errors that I received

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as tk

root = tkinter.Tk()

frame= tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

tk.Button(frame, text="Open file", command=None).grid(column=0, row=1 )
lab=tk.Label(frame, text="test test test test test test ").grid(column=0, row=2 )

#root.config(background="black")    # does nothing
#frame.config(background="black")   # Error: unknown option "-background"
#lab.config(background="black")     # Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The last error is really obvious: you assign the return value of `tk.Label().grid()` to `lab`. You have to assign the return value of `tk.Label()` to `lab` and call `.grid()` after the assignment

Comment: @Aemyl whoops, thanks. I was so frustrated when I didn'T get he background to work that I missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `frame.config(background="black")` returns the error `unknown option "-background"` because this is a `ttk.Frame`, not a `tkinter.Frame` and the background of a `ttk.Frame` is changed using a `ttk.Style` (see example below).
- `lab.config(background="black")`  gives the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'` because you did `lab = tk.Label(...).grid(...)` and `grid` returns `None` so `lab` is `None`, not a `Label`.
- `root.config(background="black")` does nothing because the widgets fill the window so you cannot see the background like naknak12 explained.

Here is an example using `ttk` widgets:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
# style configuration
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('TLabel', background='black', foreground='white')
style.configure('TFrame', background='black')

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

ttk.Button(frame, text="Open file", command=None).grid(column=0, row=1)
lab = ttk.Label(frame, text="test test test test test test ")
lab.grid(column=0, row=2)


root.mainloop()
```

And an example without `ttk`:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

tkinter.Button(frame, text="Open file", command=None).grid(column=0, row=1 )
lab = tkinter.Label(frame, text="test test test test test test ")
lab.grid(column=0, row=2)

root.configure(background='black')
lab.configure(background='black', foreground='white')
frame.configure(background='black')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A thorough and flawless answer. +1 (as soon as I have 15 rep points to give upvotes)

Comment: for anybody struggeling with "nonetype", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231563/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-config

Answer (score 1):

if you use root.config(background="black") and your resize the window, you can see the black background.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as tk
from tkinter import * 

root = tkinter.Tk()

frame= tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

Button(frame, text="Open file", command=None).grid(column=0, row=1 )
Label(frame, bg='black', fg="white", text="test test test test test test ").grid(column=0, row=2 )

root.config(background="blue")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great, I somehow missed that. Can you now please also tell me how to change the color of the individual widgets?

Comment: Thanks, +1  (as soon as I have 15 rep points to give upvotes) . Though fixing the color on the side of  the button needs an additional command, as I saw from the other answer.